# How to choose which device should used for test run in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ipod-touch

i have an iPod touch and an iPhone, both connect with my Mac and both devices have been configured so I can run my app on them individually.

I am developing a multiplayer card game, so I have to test it between these devices. Sometimes I want to debug it on the iPod touch, sometimes on the iPhone.  But I found if I connect both devices to the Mac and click build and debug, the app always runs on the iPod touch not iPhone. I have to unplug the iPod touch in order to make Xcode run the app on the iPhone

Is any way to choose which device should be used for debug? I don't want to re-connect my devices individually, so often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two provisioned devices connected to XCode use the Overview-Dropdown (that one in the left upper corner where you can switch between targets and simulator/device). Under the point "Active Executable" you can chose the device you want to deploy to and run the App with.